# man page show nothing but END, but it works after su

Tags: linux, man

1. try the 'man man' command, show nothing but END symbol
2. change to su account
3. try the 'man man' command again, it works as usual

I have no idea about this problem, any helps? thank you very much.

Comment: What is the context? OS? Version? Exact commands?

Comment: the OS is CentOS release 5.6,

Comment: The Context: man command fail to work, but everything is well if i change to super user account. Maybe i modified some login scripts unintentionally, which can cause an access problem.